# Conditional formatting on entire sheet via Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Need your help. In my Spreadsheet there is a macro that when activated test to see if a cell color in the entire set of data is pink. If one is found then the fist cell is marked pink, alerting me to the fact that on that specific row there is a pink cell somewhere.

Once I have paid attention to the pink cell, i mark it transparent again and move on to the next one.

What I need to add to the working code below is a test to see if there are no pinks .. ie..

if cell A9 is pink it means somewhere in row 9 there is a pink. I need to check if it is still there, if not make A9 transparent.

The code below is the one that marks A9 pink (as per the example above.

Code:

```
Sub pink()
Dim rcell As Range
For Each rcell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    If rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 Then
        Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, rcell.Column).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = rcell.Interior.ColorIndex
                ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select
            Loop
            If ActiveCell.Row = rcell.Row Then rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
Next rcell
For Each rcell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 Then
        Cells(rcell.Row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    End If
Next rcell
End Sub
```

To run through a scenario:

Row 1 are headings and are excluded, Column A is the column where things get marked pink..

B8 is pink thus when the macro runs, A8 goes pink, D14 is pink and thus A14 goes pink, A18 is pink but there are no more pinks in row 18 thus A18 goes transparent etc etc..

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the below transparent procedure. It will make cells in `column A` transparent if there is no pink cells in that row respectively.

```
Sub transparent()

    Dim lastRow As Long, rcell As Range, blnRed As Boolean
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 38 Then
            For Each rcell In Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
                If rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 Then
                    blnRed = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    blnRed = False
                End If
            Next

            If blnRed = False Then
                Cells(i, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```